# KendoUI and data-binding in external files

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have every view in different file, but when I'm trying to bind functions it doesn't work ( it was working when given view was in index.html ).

So for example:

button:

```
<button id="form_submit" data-bind="events: { click: submit }" >    
Sign in
</button>
```

and my viewModel:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
submit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(2);
});

kendo.bind($("#form_submit"), viewModel);
```

but as I said - when my form is in external file it doesn't work..

---

#### Solution

You have to bind everything before it's shown:

```
<div data-role="view" data-layout="form-layout" id="login-form" data-title="Login" data-use-native-scrolling="true" data-before-show="bindLogin">


function bindLogin()
{
  kendo.bind($("#form_submit"), viewModel);
}
```

then I'm getting alert.

Comment: Do you get an error or is it just not working? Is jQuery and Kendo UI loaded on the other pages?

Comment: yes, everything is loaded. i'm not getting any error. it's just not working. like the model wasn't there. I was thinking about data-before-show method and use it but don't really know how.

Comment: sounds like you are not having the form loaded at time you binding it, also move away from alerts, causes interesting Kendo behaviours.